Ellipsis is now shown with gradient text in Safari
I have a HTML block with the user icon and email, and the text color is gradient. The problem is when I shrink the screen to its minimum size, ellipsis is not displayed in Safari, although it works fine in Chrome and Firefox (and in Safari with solid color). The dots are there but they are transparent.
Is there a way to may it work somehow, or is it impossible?
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="text">userwithalonglonglonglonglongname@example.com</div>
</div>


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.text {
  font-size: 24px;
  background: linear-gradient(93deg, #2091f6 -0.06%, #21b568 99.94%);
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


Here is the Codepen with my exact component: https://codepen.io/va-deem/pen/vYMagzp

The color for the dots is picked up from the color set in the element that sets overflow.
So this snippet separates the overflow setting and the text clip setting.
The color chosen is not a perfect match of course so this is not ideal, but may be better than not seeing the dots at all.


<div class="card">

  <!-- With solid color - all Ok -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">userwithalonglonglonglonglongname@example.com</div>
  </div>


  <!-- With gradient color - ellipsis is not visible in Safari -->
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="icon2"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <span class="text2">userwithalonglonglonglonglongname@example.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<style>
  .card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
  }
  
  .icon {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px
  }
  
  .text {
    color: #21b568;
    font-size: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  /* second */
  
  .container2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
  }
  
  .icon2 {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px
  }
  
  .text2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    background: linear-gradient(93deg, #2091f6 -0.06%, #21b568 99.94%);
    background-clip: text;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    /* overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  */
  }
</style>




Thank you a lot! I've tried several ways to achieve that with wrappers, but yours really works in Safari.  I've added it as 3rd case to my codepen.
There is another problem now - it doesn't work in Firefox. :( (BTW it didn't work before also, sorry for my first mention that it worked). Are there any suggestions to make it work also in Firefox?

Ah, that's nasty. I hadn't tested on FF - it seems to act differently from both Chrome/Edge and Safari. Not sure what to do about that, will ponder.

So the original question was about Safafi and I can marked it solved, thanks to A Haworth. There is no solution for Firefox at the moment (or I don't know it) so for that browser I've just used solid color in my component.
